# What is an efficient way to extract and assign values within a String?

Tags: scala

Suppose this `String`: `Point(123 456)`.

What would be an efficient and clean way to extract and assign `123` and `456` (as `String`) to a `Tuple2` at once?

What I did:

```
val str = "Point(123 456)"
val tab = str.stripPrefix("Point(").stripSuffix(")").split("\\s")
val tuple2 = (tab(0), tab(1))
println(tuple2)  // displays the (123,456)
```

Pretty ugly ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex:

```
val str = "Point(123 456)"
val re = """Point\((\d+) (\d+)\)""".r

val re(f, s) = str
println((f, s))
```

Comment: I was trying this (regexp) at this time :) Indeed, I think it's the better solution for this case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward way is using a regex extractor.  These are quite fast, actually, for simple stuff like this--as fast as your solution.  Is it prettier?  I don't know.

```
val p = """Point\((\d+)\s(\d+)\)""".r
"Point(123 456)" match { case p(a,b) => (a,b) }
```

On my machine, extracting 10,000 such pairs takes 3.90 ms using this method, and 4.35 ms using yours (mostly due to the extra slowness of `split`).

If you need it to be faster yet for some odd reason,

```
def uuple2(s: String) = {
  if (!s.startsWith("Point(") || s(s.length-1) != ')') throw new Exception
  val i = s.indexOf(' ',6)
  if (i < 0 || i+2 >= s.length) throw new Exception
  (s.substring(6,i), s.substring(i+1,s.length-1))
}
```

This is way faster: 0.38 ms for 10k on my machine.